# Python function not executing in azure automation runbook

Tags: python, azure, azure-automation

[image]

I am working on writing a function in python azure automation runbook, where the basic gist of what I'm trying to accomplish is shown in the code below. But, I'm perplexed as when I take the code out of the function and run the code as is it all works as expected. But, when the function is used I see the output for `Start` & `End` but I don't see the function getting executed. I'm not clear the piece I miss for this to not work.

***Python:***

```
import sys
import requests
print ("Start")

def myFunction():
    # do something
    print("This is my function doing something")

myFunction()   

print ("End")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked successfully and achieved the expected outcomes when I tried it in my environment, as shown below:

First and foremost, you should add the `requests`(3.8) module/package to the `Azure Automation` runbook as you are using it in code.

***Add a package:***

*Path*:

`Azure automation account -> Python packages -> Add a Python Package`

[image]

**Note:** Versions of `Python runbook` and `packages` should be compatible with each other.

***I've created a Python runbook (3.8) and the function code was successfully executed.***

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import requests
print ("Start")
def myFunction():
print("This is my function doing something")
myFunction()
print ("End")
```

[image]

Comment: I am using hybrid worker group to run it and all I see is Start & End. I'll update my post with the results.